# Arbitrary sum of nonnegative numbers in Folland's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

On page 11, Folland, [Real Analysis 2nd Ed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160), he defined sum of nonnegative numbers as follows

[image]

Proposition 0.20 assures that the above definition agrees with the common definition for the case $X$ is countable infinite. It's also true for the case $X$ is finite and nonempty. So what about $X = \emptyset$? It is tempting to say that $\sum_{x \in \emptyset} f(x) = 0$, however, I have no idea how to prove it.

The question arises when I try to prove the following statement on page 25 in the same book
[image]

How do we prove $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. If I could comment, I would, but this may be of help:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum

You're right in saying that $\sum\limits_{x\in\varnothing} f(x) = 0$, since it is simply defined that way.